# cheerio generates strange characters

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm using cheerio to test, but I'm having trouble because it gives me character in the final html:

�

I've tried regexing and replacing function.

```
const htmlBody = /*Full HTML with correct encondig*/ 
const $ = cheerio.load(htmlBody, {
     normalizeWhitespace: false,
     xmlMode: false,
     decodeEntities: false
});

const html = $.html();
const newhtml = html.replace(/[\u00A0]/g, " ");
console.log(newhtml);
```

But this function takes it remove from me where it was in the beginning, but it generates the same characters again in other places.

It's taken me a lot of hours and I can't solve the problem. I hope someone can enlighten me

Comment: It probably has something to do with encoding. Can you show your code where you fetch html?

Comment: That's a nbsp. You're getting those because of decodeEntities I suppose.

Comment: @dziraf Yes, done. But it's clear that the problem comes from cheerio.

Comment: @pguardiario If I set decodeEntities to true, it's even worse, it generates hexageximal code in space and accents

Comment: Okay I'm subnormal, I've fixed it, just before moving the html to cheerio I converted the spaces with `htmlBody = htmlBody.replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ")`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue for many days.
In my case, I noted it is because axios.get use default encoding UTF-8, but the web site use ISO-8859-1 instead.
To solve,  we can change get by request, or change your code like this :

> 

var request = await axios.request({
method:'GET',
responseType: 'arraybuffer',
responseEncoding: 'binary',
url:'https:YourWebsiteUrl'});

var data = request.data.toString('latin1');

const $ = cheerio.load(data);